# Finding greatest common divisor of polynomials in $Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find gcd of $x^2 + 1$ and $x^5 +1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Can we just multiply them to obtain it?

$$(x^2 + 1)(x^5+1) = x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + 1 $$

is this the gcd?

Comment: Check your definition: The gcd is the greatest polynomial that divides both $x^2+1$ and $x^5+1$. That couldn't be what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2+1$ is irreducible, as any factor of it would be linear, making it have a rational root, which obviously it does not. So, if $\gcd(x^2+1,x^5+1)>1$, then, it should be $x^2+1$. However, $i\in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $x^2+1$ but not of $x^5+1$. So, $x^2+1\not| x^5+1$. Thus, $\gcd(x^2+1,x^5+1)=1$

Comment: thank so much. one quick question about gcd for polynomials. how can you handle gcd of polynomials of constants? say $gcd(2-x,9)$

Comment: you can basically factorize them as I did with this one, or you can use Euclidean Algorithm. As $9$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, its only divisors are units, thus, $gcd(2-x,9)=1$. Notice that gcd is not unique in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ as you can multiply the gcd with any rational.

Answer (score 4):

Dividing the two polynomials gives us
$$
x^5+1 = (x^3-x)(x^2+1) + (x+1)
$$
Any polynomial that divides both $x^5+1$ and $x^2+1$ must divide $x+1$.

Since $x+1$ is irreducible and does not divide $x^2+1$, any common divisor must have degree $0$. Therefore, $\gcd(x^5+1,x^2+1)=1$.

In general, use the Euclidean Algorithm to find gcds. The division above is the first step in this algorithm.

Comment: Do you need any extra steps in your division? I believe you are done, am I correct? I am asking this because they considered my question to be a duplicate of this question. Please if you do not mind take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Never really tried extended Euclidean algorithm on polynomials before, but now i see where the constants go. The possible complication is that you do not get a gcd over $\mathbb Z$ even when all coefficients are integers, it is all over $\mathbb Q$ regardless of whatever way you find to simplify the calculations. Works, though, and
$$ (x^2 + 1)(x^4 - x^3 - x^2 + x + 1) - (x^5 + 1)(x-1) = 2. $$ Here $2$ is of degree zero. If you want $1$, just divide the two polynomials I found by $2$